# What is the probability that picking $13$ cards in a deck of $52$, Spades and Hearts can't both be present?

Tags: probability

So there are $13*13$ pairs of heart/spades combinations, for each of those, we have $\binom{50}{11}$ ways to assign the remaining cards. For each pair of pairs of heart/spades combination, they overlap in $\binom{48}{9}$ situations. For each tuple of pairs of heart/spades combinations, they overlap in $\binom{46}{7}$. this pattern continues. By inclusion exclusion principle, the answer should be $\frac{13^2*\binom{50}{11}-\binom{13^2}{2}\binom{48}{9}+\binom{13^2}{3}\binom{46}{7}-\binom{13^2}{4}\binom{44}{5}+\binom{13^2}{5}\binom{42}{3}-\binom{13^2}{6}\binom{40}{1} }{\binom{52}{13}}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I follow your calculation.  In any event, there are ${26\choose13}$ ways to choose hands with neither Hearts nor Spades, and ${39\choose13}$ ways to choose hands having no Hearts (or no Spades), so a simpler application of inclusion and exclusion gives $$2{39\choose13}-{26\choose13}$$ for the numerator.